# Create IOT Device Edge Python Sdk

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

How can create IOT Edge Device?
Actually i use azure sdk service iot and created normal device, but i can't figure out how create iot edge device with azure service client sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It would be similar to how you create a normal device, only difference is that you need to add a `capabilities` property:

```
{
  deviceId: "EdgeDevice1",
  capabilities: {
    iotEdge: true
  }
}
```

You could also refer to the code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/blob/4bfff9cb24cf5f7b42728640c4ed30bf2cda4253/src/deviceExplorer.ts#L61. It is based on Node Service SDK, but is should be similar to Python Service SDK.