# How to Create and EdgeDevice with RegistryManager

Tags: python, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I see in the source file [`service/iothub_service_client_python.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/service/iothub_service_client_python.py) that the class `IoTHubRegistryManager` has methods to create and update devices and methods. They are largely used in samples and EtE tests.

Is there a counterpart to managed EdgeDevices via this python sdk? I don't see any sample or test using it.

Here on StackOverflow i found only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127513/create-iot-device-edge-python-sdk) but the answer is not complete.
They propose a solution based on some TypeScript code that adds a device with a capability but there is no such a thing on the python sdk.
For instance, the current api is

```py
def create_device(self, device_id, primary_key, secondary_key, auth_method):
    """Creates a device on IoTHub using the given parameters.

    :param device_id: The name of the device
    :type device_id: str
    :param primary_key: The primary key of the device
    :type primary_key: str
    :param secondary_key: The secondary key of the device
    :type secondary_key: str
    :param auth_method: The authentication method used to authenticate the device client
    :type auth_method: IoTHubRegistryManagerAuthMethod(Enum)
    :return: The device client instance
    :rtype: IoTHubDevice
    """
    pass
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the class [IoTHubDeviceCapabilities](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/144f780b9bbd7937fc3d7910c749c95c858d777d/service/src/iothub_service_client_python.cpp#L835-L855)? it has a bool property called iotEdge. This class can be passed as parameter to the [CreateDevice](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/144f780b9bbd7937fc3d7910c749c95c858d777d/service/src/iothub_service_client_python.cpp#L956-L995) function. However I do not see that available in the Python wrapper. You could create an issue on the Python SDK repo.